# Javascript: multiple timers vs multiple one timer multiple function calls

Tags: javascript, performance, timer

Being that javascript is single threaded, is there a different between having multiple intervals and having one interval calling multiple functions?

Comment: Are the multiple intervals expected to stay perfectly in sync so that the functions will be called in the same order? If so, I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: Can you give a code example for both scenarios?

Comment: Are you doing network callbacks or dom looping or what?

Comment: @Oran code example? There's over 70K lines of js. I think the question addresses the scenario just fine. There are a lot of timers. Depending on app usage, there could be 500+ timers at any given time.

Comment: @Jason Sebring mostly dom manipulation.

Comment: I can interpret your "scenario" in multiple ways: 1) multiple intervals, each one calling different functions. 2) multiple intervals, each one calling the same function. 3) one interval with the callback calling the same function multiple times. 4) one interval with the callback calling lots of different functions.

Comment: @Blue the timers have nothing to do with one another, so they do not need to be in sync. I'm asking striclty for performance reasons.

Comment: I like Oran's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that there's more overhead in event dispatch than there is in a simple function call, if you want to do 20 things every 100 milliseconds you're probably better off with a single handler that calls 20 functions than with 20 different timers.

With your own function, you can also ensure a consistent invocation sequence. (Browsers are pretty consistent with timer dispatch, but it's a little flaky to rely on that.)

If you're worried about this *strictly* for performance reasons, then I'd say don't worry about it unless you've got a whole lot of timers going on.

Comment: This would be stricly for performance. As I noted above we could have 500+ timers going. So I'm looking for a little overhead control. But also to start thinking about things differently going forward as we add more timers :/

Comment: What sort of intervals are these running at?  If the intervals are short, then 500 is a lot if the handlers are doing DOM manipulation. It might be better to have a single timer running at moderately high speed handling all that work. If the intervals are long (multiple seconds) then it probably doesn't matter much.

Comment: They are varied. The majority of them are at 1 second intervals as they are literal timers. There are maybe 20 or so that could be running at any given time that are around 20ms. Those are mostly animation timers though. The animation timers are cleared when not in use so there usually aren't very many running and we've pushed most of the animation to CSS.

Comment: You answered my question though about performance. I wasn't sure if it was worth exploring a single global timer handler or not.

Answer (score 5):

Check out Google's [analysis of timer use for Gmail Mobile](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/07/gmail-for-mobile-html5-series-using.html).  The short version is that creating lots of timers with a delay of one second or more doesn't noticeably impact performance.  But lots of timers with 100-200ms delays made the UI feel sluggish.  As a result, they chose to use a hybrid approach of a single global high-frequency timer for the short timers and separate timers for longer timers.